# Showing that log( e^X + e^Y - 1 ) is approximately normal

Tags: distributions, lognormal-distribution, bivariate, moment-generating-function

### Problem (not course-related)

I believe that if $X$ and $Y$ are iid $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, where $\mu>0$ and $\sigma^2$ is not too large compared to $\mu$, then:

$$\log(e^X + e^Y-1) \approx N(\mu^{*}, (\sigma^2)^{*} )$$

for some new mean $\mu^{*}$ and variance $(\sigma^2)^{*}$. I believe this to be true due to simulations like the following, which hold for various choices of the parameters:

```
X = rnorm(N, mean=1.5, sd=0.8)
Y = rnorm(N, mean=1.5, sd=0.8)
thing = log( exp(X) + exp(Y) - 1)
summary(thing); sd(thing)
hist( thing )
```

I would like to: (1) prove this; (2) estimate $\mu^{*}$ and $(\sigma^2)^{*}$; and ideally (3) know how closely the approximation holds.

### My attempt

I tried to find the MGF of $Z \equiv \log(e^X + e^Y-1)$, hoping it would like somewhat like the MGF of a Normal:

$$M_Z(t) \equiv \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \exp \Big\{ t \log \left( e^x + e^y - 1 ) \right) \Big\} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \; dx \; dy $$

$$M_Z(t) \equiv \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \left( e^x + e^y - 1 \right)^t f_{X,Y}(x,y) \; dx \; dy $$

$$M_Z(t) = \int_0^{\infty} f_Y(y) \Bigg[ \int_0^{\infty} \left( e^x + e^y - 1 \right)^t f_{X}(x) \; dx \Bigg] \; dy $$

$$M_Z(t) = \int_0^{\infty} f_Y(y) \; E_X \Big[ \left( e^x + e^y - 1 \right)^t  \Big] \; dy $$

$$M_Z(t) = E_Y \Bigg[ E_X \Big[ \left( e^x + e^y - 1 \right)^t  \Big] \Bigg] $$

Because the inner expectation was a mess, I approximated it using a second-order Taylor expansion. Then I did the same thing with the outer expectation. I ended up with a gigantic mess that bore no obvious resemblance to the Normal MGF. I would appreciate any suggestions about other ways to prove this.

Comment: This cannot be exactly true: note that there is a positive probability that $Z$ is undefined (if $e^X + e^Y \leq 1$). So at best you could hope for approximately normal. So you should use $\dot \sim$ instead of $\sim$.

Comment: Yes, of course you're right that it would only hold approximately. I've fixed the notation in line 2.

Comment: It isn't apparent how your attempt says much, if anything, about $Z$: it never uses the logarithm. Instead, begin by simplifying: without any loss of generality, dividing $X$ and $Y$ by $\mu$ allows you to assume $X-1,Y-1\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2/\mu)$. Since $\sigma^2/\mu \ll 1$ by assumption, you may approximate $\log(e^X+e^Y-1)=\log(e(e^{X-1}+e^{Y-1})-1)$ with first-order MacLaurin series in $X$ and $Y$ and you're practically done. Since such an approximation is linear in $X$ and $Y$, you already know it produces a Normal distribution. You just have to work out its parameters.

Comment: @whuber, thank you! I'll give it a try. (Also, I added a line to my attempt to clarify why the log drops out.)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying your derivation.  Obviously I had not studied it in detail.  In general though, unless $t$ is rational, it rarely pays to replace $\exp(t\log(x))$ with $x^t$: the former is usually more amenable to analysis.